# using Mosaic to new Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, image-mosaic

I have 2 tiffs to mosaic which overlap and there is a order to display them right,  When using Mosaic to New Raster the first file I input will be overlapped by the second input file?

Answer (score 2):

There is a switch 'Mosaic Operator' which controls the order of layers. If you keep default which is 'LAST', the former will be overwritten by the latter as you assume.